# Loading an Image object into pygame

Tags: image, pygame

I'm making a game were you can set the background image yourself.
The selected image is resized to make it fit the purpose, and then i want to load the picture into pygame.

I've something like:

```
image = Image.open('file')
image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

And now I want to load image into pygame.

of course I can use:

```
image.save(outfile, "JPEG")
background = pygame.image.load('outfile')
```

Is there a nice way without having to save the image to my hard drive?
Or is it possible that pygame resizes the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pygame.transform.scale()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) to resize an image:

> **pygame.transform.scale()**
>
> *resize to new resolution*
>
> `scale(Surface, (width, height), DestSurface = None) -> Surface`
>
> Resizes the Surface to a new resolution. This is a fast scale operation that does not sample the results.
>
> An optional destination surface can be used, rather than have it create a new one. This is quicker if you want to repeatedly scale something. However the destination must be the same size as the (width, height) passed in. Also the destination surface must be the same format.

So you don't have to use PIL.